# Predicate logic - structure where two things exist and aren't the same?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I saw this example pop-up: `(∀x: P(x) ⇒ Q(x)) ∧ ¬(∃x: P(x) ∧ Q(x))` and it said to be trivial to find a structure/universe where this is true, yet I cannot find it.

I have tried splitting the problem, yet it always results in something that does not work.
(Like giving `P = (1)`and `Q = (1,2)` etc.)

Any ideas what this may be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the case where $P(x)$ is always false.

Comment: Omg.. obviously. Thank you so much! I went way too deep and I passed the obvious.